# curl GET with params of complex type value

Tags: json, api, curl

I have two class/records.

```
record HeightRange{
    low: Height
    high: Height
}
```

Also:

```
record Height{
    size: float
    unit: String
}
```

Now I'm creating new API endpoints with `HeightRange` as query param, which is complex type. For example I can do:

`curl "http://localhost:123/resource/?q=method1&heightRange=(low:(size:1,unit:M), high:(size:2,unit:M))`

or

`curl "http://localhost:123/resource/?q=method1&heightRange.low=(size:1,unit:M)&heightRange.high=(size:2,unit:M))`

But neither really works. The 2nd one would work if `heightRange.low` is primitive type like float or int. The tricky thing is we have complex key(heightRange has low and high), and the value is also complex type(size and unit).

So what's the proper curl format for such case involving complex type value?

Comment: A horrible hack could be to translate the GET query string in a single big base64 string blob and let the server decode the complex object from that string.

Comment: We don't know you API, but uri-encode perhaps? `curl "http://localhost:123/resource/?q=method1&heightRange=%28low%3A%28size%3A1%2Cunit%3AM%29%2C%20high%3A%28size%3A2%2Cunit%3AM%29%29"` for instance.